# string argument in thread function

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm having problems passing a string to a thread function using pthread_create
I get strange charactes when i run the progam
here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define NTHREADS 3



void *myFun(void *ptr){
     char * string;
     string = (char *) ptr;
     printf("string: %s\n", string);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    char* thread_args[NTHREADS];
    int i;
    char* string;
    /* spawn threads */
    for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i){
        string = "file1.txt";
        thread_args[i] = string;
        if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, myFun, (void *) &thread_args[i]) != 0){ 
            printf("Error creating thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
  /* Wait for threads to finish */
    for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can pass a int without problems doing a cast to int in the same way i did in the code, but with char it is not working.

Comment: What does _"not working"_ mean? What is your debugger saying?

Comment: There's no point in your `thread_args` variable - especially not being an array.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the pointer, not the address of the pointer.

```
if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, myFun, (void *) thread_args[i])
                                                     ^
```